# Como usar um site no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Então, eu criei um sistema em php que salva os números entre outras coisas dos funcionários da empresa, eu utilizo o xampp em meu computador, eu queria saber como eu faço para colocar o sistema em php no servidor e fazer com que ele consiga se aberto nos computadores da empresa...

Comment: Você usa windows server? Se sim, pode fazer isso com o iis, em conjunto com o no-ip

Comment: Sim, uso o Windows server, teria como fazer um exemplo porque eu não tenho nenhuma pratica com o Windowns Server

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=34679 baixa ele primeiro, depois veja esse tutorial, acho que vai te ajudar no que você precisa. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2418.configurando-o-iis-7-no-windows-server-2008-pt-br.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim também:

Primeiro, pegar as portas do Apache XAMP:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso aqui, peguei a 80.

Depois, ver o IPV4 da maquina, no meu caso é 192.168.0.20

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Indo no PC da mesma rede, é so acessar: 192.168.0.20:80, que vai entrar normal no servidor.

Comment: Aí tipo se minha pasta fosse agenda eu entraria como 192.168.0.20:80/agenda

Comment: No caso, sim! Se existir essa pasta agenda dentro de htdocs

Comment: Você pode usar o nome do seu PC no lugar do IP:80 (muito útil caso seu IP não seja fixo na rede). O nome do seu PC você pode verificar em Painel de Controle\Todos os Itens do Painel de Controle\Sistema. Ex: http://meu-pc/agenda

Comment: valeu, era isso mesmo